# Customization from code behind when exporting web pages to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, pdf

I just wonder if anybody would provide any links for me to customize my grid view and table when exporting from aspx webpages to pdf? Because I have no idea how to style them from code behind and it looks terrible.

I tried to add border to my grid view and shift my table aligned to the right but it does not work:

```
gvProduct.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
        gvProduct.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
        gvProduct.HeaderRow.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        gvProduct.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
        gvProduct.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
        gvProduct.Style.Add("font-size", "6px");
        gvProduct.Style.Add("border-width", "5px");
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Packaging Slip", titleFont));
        var benefitInfoTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        benefitInfoTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        benefitInfoTable.SpacingBefore = 5;
        benefitInfoTable.SpacingAfter = 5;
        benefitInfoTable.DefaultCell.Border = 5;
        benefitInfoTable.SetWidths(new int[] { 1, 4 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new object of ItextSharp Style sheet:

```
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new       TextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
```

Create CSS as per your requirement as below:

```
styles.LoadTagStyle("Your Class Name", "height", "30px");
 styles.LoadStyle("Your Class Name", "font-weight", "bold");
```

Assign the StyleSheet Object to HTMLWorker Object as Below:

```
 HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
   htmlparser.SetStyleSheet(styles);
```

It may help you.